# Do I need Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to build a webpage that shows information only to allowed users and allows those users to modify that information. I want to use Facebook to authenticate the allowed users. I would have those users' Facebook IDs stored in a database and check a logging in user ID against the ones stored to see if this person can access the information.

Using the Facebook JavaScript SDK I can log a user in and obtain his ID on the client side. But I'm not sure how I should proceed from there.

I believe I need to use PHP SDK to do what I described. Am I right? Or is there a way to use only JavaScript SDK that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use **PHP SDK** or **Javascript SDK** or **No SDK** or **any combination**!

It's flexible, it's on you how you like to code.

But since you are using JS SDK for login, if you wish you may use only JS SDK for all the functionalities on your app!

> is there a way to use only JavaScript SDK that I am unaware of?

What exactly you mean by that? Just like you use JS SDK for login using `FB.login()`, you can call other APIs ([Graph APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/)) like -

`FB.api("/me")` `FB.api("/me/feed")` `FB.api("/me/accounts")` etc. etc.

You can go through this - [Facebook SDK for Javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/v2.2)

---

**Edit**

To make the request secure, so that no one misuses your API and get the user's data, you may send client's ***access token* instead of facebook id**. This access token is temporary in nature (valid for 2 hours only)

I'll explain this a bit-

1. client will send *access token* to the server
2. server will VERIFY this token. eg:

   ```
   \GET https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={token-to-inspect}&access_token={app-token}
   ```

   you may use simple `curl` req or `file_get_contents()` to make this request

   [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#checktoken)
3. If it's a valid one, get the `user_id` from the response and send the appropriate data.
4. If the token fails, you may send authentication error to your application.

Since token expires after some time, nobody can misuse the token!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I meant is how I would do it only with JS. The way I can think of is to use the API to get the user ID, send it to the server using JS and if that ID corresponds to an allowed user then the server sends back the data. But wouldn't this be insecure? Anyone who knew an allowed ID could bypass the Facebook login and just send that ID to the server and get back the data, right?

Comment: I think that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!